# how to add particular view to the Quick Launch section of the page in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, user-interface, sharepoint-2010

How do I add a particular view to the Quick Launch section of the page in Sharepoint instead (or in addition to) of the usual "default" view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the view you are interested in, copy the URL and paste it in a new item in Site Actions / Site Settings / Navigation or Site Actions / Site Settings / Quick Launch.